# Inserting zeros between the frequencies does not reconstruct the original signal using DFT / Inverse DFT?

Tags: dft, c#

I start with a 2 Hz signal.  The signal is sampled at a 4.167 Hz sample rate.  See https://nyquist.foxping.com/ => "DFT Images 3 zeros.pdf" for images.  The intent is to reconstruct the image on the top left side.

I convert that sampled signal into frequencies via DFT:

```
public Complex[] acplxConvertSignalToDft(double[] adSignalYValues)
{
  int iNumOfValues = adSignalYValues.Length;
  Complex[] acplxFrequencies = new Complex[iNumOfValues];
  for (int ii = 0; ii < iNumOfValues; ii++) 
  {
    acplxFrequencies[ii] = 0;
    for (int iii = 0; iii < iNumOfValues; iii++) 
    {
      acplxFrequencies[ii] += adSignalYValues[iii] * 
        Complex.Exp(-Complex.ImaginaryOne *
        2 * Math.PI * (ii * iii) /
        Convert.ToDouble(iNumOfValues));
    }
    acplxFrequencies[ii] = acplxFrequencies[ii] / iNumOfValues;
  }
  return acplxFrequencies;
}//acplxConvertSignalToDft
```

I insert 3 zeros between each frequency.  Then I convert those frequencies to a signal via Inverse DFT:

```
public double[] adConvertDftToSignal(Complex[] acplxFrequencies)
{
  int iNumOfValues = acplxFrequencies.Length; 
  double[] adInverseDftSignalYValues = new double[iNumOfValues];
  for (int ii = 0; ii < iNumOfValues; ii++) 
  {
    Complex cplxSum = 0;
    for (int iii = 0; iii < iNumOfValues; iii++) 
    {
      cplxSum += acplxFrequencies[iii] *
        Complex.Exp(Complex.ImaginaryOne *
        2 * Math.PI * (iii * ii) /
        Convert.ToDouble(iNumOfValues));
    }
    //Use real values imaginary values should be close to zero
    adInverseDftSignalYValues[ii] = cplxSum.Real;
  }
return adInverseDftSignalYValues;
}//adConvertDftToSignal
```

Per Nyquist Sampling criteria, sampling at slightly faster than twice the highest frequency, results in all of the frequencies.  As I understand, adding zeros to those frequencies can reconstruct the original signal.  I think this is how music is stored ... less data stored, but original sound is recreated.

I had assumed that inserting zeros between the frequencies would reconstruct the original signal ... did not.  What is the correct procedure?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Peter K.'s response is correct.  Inserting zeros between the max frequency in the middle of the frequency spectrum reconstructs the signal before the signal was sampled.

See https://nyquist.foxping.com/ => "DFT Images 2 Hz, 0 zeros.pdf" and "DFT Images 2 Hz, 200 zeros.pdf" for images.  The intent was to reconstruct the image on the top left side.

There is a slight difference which will be discussed in another post => [Adding the first left point freq to the right side end to make it perfectly symmetrical does not fix the problem?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79078/adding-the-first-left-point-freq-to-the-right-side-end-to-make-it-perfectly-symm)

Answer (score 1):

So, let's try this. Here's the original signal:

[image: Original signal]

and then we decimate it by a factor of 24:

[image: Decimated signal]

and then we try to reconstruct it:

[image: Reconstructed overlaid with original]

which mostly works.

There's a a little bit of inaccuracy due to the amplitude mismatch and there're a few phase wobbles. But it mostly seems to hang together.

The bit you're missing: to upsample, you need to stuff zeros between the low frequency components in the FFT and their (complex conjugate) high frequency components.

---

## Python code below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

T = 201
fs = 100
t = np.arange(T)/fs
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*2*t)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t,x)

x_decimated = x[1:T:24]
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x_decimated)

x_d_fft = np.fft.fft(x_decimated)
x_d_fft_padded = np.concatenate((x_d_fft[0:5], np.zeros(len(x)-len(x_d_fft)), x_d_fft[5:9]))
x_interpolated = np.fft.ifft(24*x_d_fft_padded)
plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(t,x)
plt.plot(t, np.real(x_interpolated))
plt.plot(t, np.imag(x_interpolated))
```

Comment: Where are the zeros being added?  On the frequency spectrum provided, remove the zeros between the freqs, and add zeros after the last freq?  If so, how many zeors? "DFT Images 0 zeros.pdf" shows the freqs with no zeros.

Comment: @ttom the Python line with `concatenate` is where zeros are added.

Comment: I do not know Python code.  Where are zeros added?

Comment: @ttom The vector has: the first five DFT coefficients, then lots of zeros, then the last four DFT coefficients.

Comment: Your freq plot has 8 freqs.  Put zeros between the first 4 freqs and the last 4 freqs?  Also, why are four freqs displayed.  There is only 1 freq (2 Hz).

Comment: @ttom There is no frequency plot. There are nine time samples with indexes 0 to 8.

Comment: Using the images at https://nyquist.foxping.com/, I am starting with 2 Hz.  In "DFT Images 0 zeros.pdf", the left side middle shows 2 Hz on the freq spectrum.  The right side middle also shows 2 Hz.  Where do I add zeros?

Comment: @ttom between index 4 and index 5 of your 9 sample frequency plot [0 1 2 3 4 <insert zeros here> 5 6 7 8].